# Highcharts area direction

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Is it possible to show gradient area on Highchart over the line?

I need the chart to have the area over the line and not under it. I would be happy for help because i did not find a solution using the Highcharts API.

Comment: You can see the example of area under the line here: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the `threshold` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.threshold)) option. For example:

```
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        // ... for brevity
        threshold: Infinity
    }
}
```

Or see [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/2b5fs84y/) of it in action. This utilized the following:

> If `Infinity` or `-Infinity`, the area between the graph and the corresponing Y axis extreme is filled (since v6.1.0).